# Mappings between Data Models in n-Tier Systems !

Tags: serialization, mapping, data-modeling

Greetings Overflowers,

I'm really tiered of over-thinking this subject

Here are typical mappings:

Relation DB Model <> Server OO Model <> Serialized Model <> Client OO Model

<> stands for bi-directional mapping

I'm currently using Java for my backend and ExtJS (JavaScript library) for my frontend.
It makes sense to serialize to/from Java and JSON objects. What is your recommended JSON serialization library ? why ?

How about your recommendation on the DB side ? I really hate the overhead and complexity of relational-OO mapping. I love objectdb's support for the clean JPA2, but it is expensive. Sadly, it seems to be the only OO db to support JPA2 natively. What are your thoughts on this especially when it comes to API cleanness and performance ?

How do you manage your data stores using relational DBs ? do you, for e.g., use wrapper classes to wrap datasets ? or directly manipulate datasets without mapping to objects ? do you map directly to JSON, for e.g., from those datasets ?

Anything for compression/encryption of serialized data before sending ? and how to reverse it back using JavaScript ?

Im really looking for a clean and fast stack of APIs to do my job

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Any good books on the subject ? is it related to design patterns ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you committed to using Java on the server?  If not, node.js with a MongoDb database might eliminate a couple links in the chain, because Mongo lets you store JSON documents and your server app is written in Javascript.  so all one language, all one data representation, and node.js+mongo provides reportedly amazing performance and scalability.  You also eliminate SQL, dealing with the db data directly as Javascript objects. You also don't define a db schema - you store JSON documents.

I'm personally moving all my personal server-side development to node.js and mongo for precisely these reasons.  Much simpler, probably faster, and more easily scalable.

You also get to use the same language throughout the stack, and Javascript is a more expressive language than Java in its refactoring power.